# solution of an infinite horizon optimization problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

Give the following formulation:

$\min_{\{x_s(t):\forall s,t\}} \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} \mathbf{1}\left(\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T}  \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{y_s(t)}{x_s(t)}\leq 1\right)$

$s.t. \qquad \quad y_s(t+1)=f(y_s(t),x_s(t))$

what math tool can give the optimal solution to this problem?

Comment: As stated, it looks like the problem decouples over all $s \in \mathcal{S}$, which makes me wonder why you are formulating the problem with $s$ indices.  Anyway, the decoupled problem solves, for each $s \in \mathcal{S}$, the problem of finding $x_s(t)$ values for $t \geq 0$ to minimize $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T y_s(t)/x_s(t)$ subject to $y_s(t+1)=f(y_s(t),x_s(t))$ for all $t$.  Do that for each $s \in \mathcal{S}$, then count the ones that have optimal limiting values less than or equal to 1.

Comment: Of course, the subproblem for each distinct $s$ may still be difficult to solve.  It depends on the function $f$.  It may be useful to look for "periodic" solutions. For example, period-2 solutions are defined by vectors $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ such that $y_2=f(y_1,x_1), y_1 = f(y_2,x_2)$.  I wonder if, under suitable compactness assumptions, one could prove an optimal solution exists with a  periodic structure.